# linux mint 19 installer restarting

Tags: linux-mint

as a project I have been building a supercomputer cluster out  of old(ish) computers. I decided to use Linux mint and successfully installed it on two out of 5 computers however on the 3rd computer I encountered an error. the installer would run fine up until the select the drive screen at which point it reverts to the previous screen (select partioning)and this ends up in a loop (parting to drive select to portioning to drive select ect), I have tried both drives and nether make any change. it is not the boot media as it worked on the pervious 2 devices. I made a new boot usb a (this time 64 bit) and encountered the exact same issue. the computer specs are as follows:

1. dual core intel chip
2. 1.5 gz chip
3. 2 GB ram
4. 580 GB(one 500 GB and one 80 GB drives)
5. previously running windows XP

I am unable to install the media on the 4th computer due to a issue with the boot loader.

Comment: Not much of a supercomputer cluster, when a single modern computer is faster.  But, have if you are having fun, go at it :)

Comment: knew someone would say that, quite frankly most computers do not have 9 cores and 12 GB of ram. the computers are not all identical.

Comment: care to explain the down vote?

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for the help mate, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the hardware is good, then something is likely wrong with partition table. Use Gparted and delete the current partition table and create a new one, then install Mint.

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm! Cluster up and running. Said cluster now running some pi calculations!